# How to get a value from a channel without waiting for it

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, go, goroutine

In Go, if I try to receive from a channel, the program's execution is going to be stopped until some value is in the channel. However, what I would like to do is let the program execution continue and, if there's a value in the channel, act on it.

The pseudo-code I have in mind is something like this:

```
mychan := make(chan int, 1)

go someGoRoutine(mychan) // This might put some value in mychan at some point

for {
    if something in "mychan" {
        // Remove the element from "mychan" and process it
    } else {
        // Other code
    }
}
```

As I understand, I cannot simply use `v <- mychan` because that would block the program execution until a value is available. What would be the way to do this in Go?

Comment: maybe you need less buffer size, generally you need have some value to do something and it dependents on your business, but you would get less data and run thread for each. I have to say that there is no warranty to get data faster in lower buffer size, because it's up to reader implementation when to response some data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what [select](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) is for. For example:

```
for {
        select {
        case v := <-c1:
                // process v
        case v, ok := <-c2:
                // Second form, '!ok' -> c2 was closed
        default:
                // receiving was not done
        }
}
```